# msfconsole pop-out an error : Bundler faild to load , cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

Tags: rubygems, bundler, metasploit, parrot-os

So l installed parrot OS on my PC hard drive , 
after that l updated hole system and tried to run `MSFCONSOLE` .
After l execute that command l get this error :

```
Bundler failed to load and return this error:

cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

you may need to uninstall or upgrade bundler
```

After this l uninstall bundler and install it again it didn't work .

l tried to upgrade it as well but it said that all packages are up to date .

Also l ran `gem install bundler`
it successfully installed bundler and 1 gem but after that it pops-out same message after l ran `msfconsole`

Is it the right way to fix this..?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the Terminal and run the following commands:

1. `cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework`.
2. Upgrade your bundler/setup : `gem install bundler`.
3. Install bundle: `bundle install`.
4. `gem update --system`.
5. Restart Metasploit.

Answer (score 3):

Update gem in your system by typing this in the terminal:
sudo gem update --system

Answer (score 0):

Update your system by typing this in the terminal:

```
get update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

One Kali Linux in a vm I had the same problem and the following fixed it:

gem install bundler:1.17.3

msfdb reinit